# Getting an enumerated value out of an Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, generics, enums, spinner

I've written the class below to let me get an enumerated value out of an Android Spinner.

There are two lines in `getValue()` neither of which compile.

How should I do this?

```
public class EnumSpinnerListener<T extends Enum> implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private String mValue = null;

    public EnumSpinnerListener(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        adapterView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        mValue = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return Enum.valueOf(T.class, mValue); // cannot select from a type variable
        return T.valueOf(mValue); // valueOf(java.lang.Class<T>, String) in enum cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), `T` will have no meaning at runtime, which is why the expression `T.class` is illegal. The workaround is to reference a `Class<T>` instance:

```
public class EnumSpinnerListener<T extends Enum<T>> // note the correction here
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final Class<T> type;

    private String mValue = null;

    public EnumSpinnerListener(Class<T> type, AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        this.type = type;
        adapterView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return Enum.valueOf(type, mValue);
    }
}
```